# Is there a way to convert std::vector<const T*> to std::vector<T*> without extra allocations?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Let's say I have a `Storage` of some `Object`s which has a method that aggregates pointers to some of the `Objects` in a vector. Like this:

```
class Storage
{
public:
   std::vector<Object*> aggregate_some_objects(); // non-const version
   std::vector<const Object*> aggregate_some_objects() const; // const version

private:
   std::unordered_map<size_t, Object> m_objects; // data is stored 
                                                 // by-value in a non-vector container
}
```

Generally, there is way to avoid copy-paste in implementation of const + non-const method pairs by calling one of them inside the other with the help of `const_cast`. Here however this is not possible because the return types of the methods are different.

The most straightforward way to avoid copy-paste here would be to call `const` version from a non-`const` version and use the returned `std::vector<const T*>` to populate a separate `std::vector<T*>`. However this would lead to at least 2 heap allocation (one for each vector). I would like to avoid the allocations associated with the second vector.

I wonder if there is way to write something like

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T*> remove_const_from_vector_of_ptrs(std::vector<const T*>&& input)
{
   std::vector<T*> ret;
   // do some magic stuff here that does not involve
   // more memory allocations
   return ret;
}
```

Thus, allowing to write

```
std::vector<const Object*> Storage::aggregate_some_objects() const
{
   // non-trivial implementation
}

std::vector<Object*> Storage::aggregate_some_objects() 
{
   auto objects = const_cast<const Storage*>(this)->aggregate_some_objects();
   return remove_const_from_vector_of_ptrs(std::move(objects));
}
```

There is no 'release' method in `std::vector` (like `std::unique_ptr` for example) that allows transferring of memory ownership - and for a very good reason, so I expect that this is not possible.

I also understand that if it were possible, it would be a dangerous operation that should be generally avoided, just as `const_cast`. But a careful usage in cases like this seems more beneficial than copy-pasting.

**Edit:** added clarifications to what do I mean by 'extra' allocations and changed `Storage::aggregate_objects()` to `Storage::aggregate_some_objects()` to better indicate that the implementation of these methods is more complex then a range-based loop - hence the desire to avoid copy-pasting the implementation.

Comment: Your functions return by value, so allocate a new vector every time. What "extra allocations" are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Yes, the functions return by-value which means that at least one heap allocation must happen (best case scenario - I know the size of the returned vector and can call `vector::reserve`). I am talking about allocations that will take place in the most simple implementation of the methods in question that does not involve copy-pasting: non-`const` version calls `const` version (which returns `std::vector<const T*>`) and populates a separate `std::vector<T*>`. Creation of a separate vector will result in at least 1 more ('extra') allocation which I'd like to avoid. Clarified this in the question.

Comment: If you goal is simply to avoid duplicating the function body then don't try to do anything dumb with casts and undefined behaviour, just write a function template that returns `std::vector<T*>` and then invoke it with `T` == `Object` or with `T` == `const Object`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is: no. `std::vector<Object*>` and `std::vector<const Object*>` are two different, independent classes. They are as different from each other as `class A` is from `class B`. It is often thought that just because both of them start with `std::vector`, that they are somehow related to each other. This is not true, and for that reason there is no way to convert one to the other, "in place". Each one of these vector classes own their corresponding internal `data()`, and will not willingly give it up to some other, strange class.

The long answer is still no, but in many cases it's possible to work around this in order to avoid manual code duplication. The truth of it is that code duplication is inevitable in most of these kinds of situations, and the best that can be done is to avoid manual code duplication.

One common approach is have both the constant and the mutable class method be facades for a single, shared, private template:

```
// Header file:

class Storage {

public:

    std::vector<const Object*> aggregate_objects() const;

    std::vector<Object*> aggregate_objects();

private:

    template<typename v_type> void make_aggregate_objects(v_type &v) const;
};

// In the translation unit:

template<typename v_type> void Storage::make_aggregate_objects(v_type &v) const
{
     // Now, create 'v' here... v.reserve(), v.push_back(), etc...
}

std::vector<const Object*> Storage::aggregate_objects() const
{
     std::vector<const Object *> v;

     make_aggregate_objects(v);

     return v;
}

std::vector<Object*> Storage::aggregate_objects()
{
     std::vector<const Object *> v;

     make_aggregate_objects(v);

     return v;
}
```

The compiler will still generate two nearly identical chunks of code, but at least it's not you doing all the typing.

Another, similar approach, is to pass a lambda to the template function instead of passing a vector object, with the private template function using the lambda function as a callback, to construct the returned vector. With a bit of type erasure, and some help from `std::function`, the private class method can be turned into an ordinary method, instead of a template method.

Comment: This seems like the most complete answer with the simplest solution. Thanks! Just want to add one thing: although you call this approach common, I want to note that if I'd encounter code like that I would probably scratch my head for a second or two thinking why the `v_type` is templatized. Is this intended to be used with different vectors (or for completely different entities if the argument of `make_aggregate_objects` was `std::vector<T>& v`)? I think `std::conditional_t` approach proposed by **tmlen** adds clarity to such misunderstandings, perhaps some people will find it more useful.

Comment: @SergeyNikitin - the primary advantage of using `std::conditional_t` is to force a wrong parameter to result in a compilation error earlier in the process, as opposed to a compilation error buried somewhere inside the function, and referencing some internal, undocumented members of C++ library containers that do not apparently have to do with anything. I guess that after ~15 years of deciphering C++ compilation errors, this is of very little value to me; and I gain the ability to repurpose the template with other containers, for free.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to convert `std::vector<const Object*>` to `std::vector<Object*>` without reallocating memory and copying the pointers, because `std::vector` is a container and owns its memory.

Using `reinterpret_cast` may work in this case, but is undefined behavior and depends on the implementation of `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<const Object*> const_vec = ...;
std::vector<Object*>& vec = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<Object*>&>(const_vec);
```

A solution to avoid `const_cast` or unnecessary allocations would be a third, templated function:

```
template<typename Stor>
static auto Storage::aggregate_objects_(Stor&)
-> std::vector<std::conditional_t<std::is_const<Stor>::value, const Object*, Object*>>
{
    ...
}
```

where `Stor` can be `Storage` or `const Storage`.

Then `aggregate_objects()` would be implemented as:

```
std::vector<const Object*> Storage::aggregate_objects() const {
    return aggregate_objects_(*this);
}

std::vector<Object*> Storage::aggregate_objects() {
    return aggregate_objects_(*this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your functions return by value so always allocate anyway - what "extra allocations" are you talking about?

If you simply store `vector<Object*>` internally then it's trivial to solve your problem:

```
std::vector<Object*> Storage::aggregate_objects()
{ return m_data; };

std::vector<const Object*> Storage::aggregate_objects() const
{ return std::vector<const Object*>(m_data.begin(), m_data.end()); }
```

**Edit:** in response to your updated question:

You should not write bad code just to avoid copy&paste of a function body!

There's no need to duplicate the function body, or to write bad code with dangerous or risky casts, just use a template that gets called by both functions, as Sam Varshavchik's answer shows.

Comment: I've edited the original question to clarify what I mean by 'extra' allocations. Also I have expanded code snippets to give a better idea about how the data is stored which would hopefully give better idea about what problem is being solved.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is no, `std::vector<T*>` and `std::vector<const T*>` are 2 different objects that cannot be interchanged.

However, armed with the knowledge of `std::vector` internals, it should be fairly easy to see that whether we store `T*` or `const T*` inside `std::vector`, it does not matter from it's perspective.

Hence, one way to do this would be to force-cast the result from one type to another. So:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T*> remove_const_from_result(std::vector<const T*>&& input) {
  return reinterpret_cast<std::vector<T*>&>(input);
}
```

The big caveat with this approach is that we can only do this if we are fairly confident about the internals of the container we are force-casting.

Note that this still does not help with your original problem, namely that you have 2 different member functions, and you are essentially `const_cast`-ing the result of one into another.

To illustrate, let me assume you have a getter function without the `std::vector`, so take this:

```
struct Foo {
  const Bar* bar() const { return &bar_; }
  Bar* bar() { return const_cast<Bar*>(bar()); }

 private:
  Bar bar_;
};
```

A better way to do this, IMO, would be to expose a templatized function internally, and use that instead. So, `Foo` becomes:

```
struct Foo {
  const Bar* bar() const { return get_internal<const Bar*>(&bar_); }
  Bar* bar() { return get_internal<Bar*>(&bar_); }

 private:
  Bar bar_;
  template <typename T>
  T get_internal(std::remove_const<T>::type ptr) const { return ptr; }
};
```

So, similarly, for your example, you can use a same approach:

```
struct Storage {
  std::vector<const Object*> aggregate_objects() const { return aggregate_internal<const Object*>(); }
  std::vector<Object*> aggregate_objects() { return aggregate_internal<Object*>(); }

 private:
  template <typename T>
  std::vector<T*> aggregate_internal() const {
    // actual aggregate function where T* can be const T* also.
  }
}
```

Comment: Your "force cast" approach doesn't compile, and would not avoid extra allocations even if it did compile because it returns by value (like the original).

Comment: The "force cast" example should read: `template<class T> std::vector<T*>& remove_const_from_result(std::vector<const T*>& input) { return reinterpret_cast<std::vector<T*>&>(input); }`

Comment: @JonathanWakely  RVO should ensure no extra allocation is done.

Comment: @Arindam: You updated it to something that wasn't what I wrote, though! Your version *still* makes an extra copy of the whole vector. If you're going to play around with this stuff, you should test your code on http://melpon.org/wandbox/ first (using some `T` that prints a message on construction/destruction). And no, Jonathan Wakeley is highly unlikely to be wrong on these matters. ;)  RVO/copy-elision doesn't apply because `input` is a parameter; and you aren't moving-from `input` anyway.

Comment: @Quuxplusone That reinterpret_cast is undefined behaviour. My answer shows how to do it without UB, trying to do it with a cast is a very very bad idea. Just say no.

Comment: Agreed that it's undefined behavior (and might screw up type-based aliasing, leading to *actual* runtime problems in practice, so it's not purely theoretical). But Arindam's current code doesn't even achieve any efficiency upside to "make up for" that downside; it's exactly the same as copying the whole vector, but with the *added* downside of UB.